# How to change my default save location from sd to internal memory card of phone?

Tags: file-system

I have a dooge x5 max pro android 6.0 . How can i change the save location by simple steps?

Answer (score 0):

The steps for changing default Storage is the same for many Android devices.  You just need to go in **Settings > Storage** and charge the **Preferred Install Location** to SD Card.

Comment: ohh. when i press to change a setting it does nothing...

Comment: What do you mean by it does nothing? What do you expect

Comment: for example, i want to change the time. when i go there and i press the corresponding setting it does nothing like i didn't press it

Comment: Are the fields grayed out? Can you upload a screenshot of the setting?

Comment: white. when i press something, then the pressing is grey field, without result

Comment: I can't fully understand the issue without a screenshot. Can you upload that?

Comment: this phone is not mine. my mother has it. if she has a virus, how they do it? they doesn't serf in web

Comment: I don't get you! What are we talking about? The question is asking how to set a default storage. Did my answer solve it? If yes please accept this answer.

Comment: And ask a new question.